# moisture in ac return duct

Tags: hvac

I have had numerious companies come to my house to resolve a on going issue.When our ac unit stops we get humidity comming back through our return.our duct work has no leaks, and everything is tight. we have been told to get a larger unit smaller unit install a damper install a dehue to ac unit it is a package unit we live in the south in south carolina. can anybody out there tell me how to resolve this issue. the house is 12 years old ,and we have a encapsulated crawl space.
respectfully
sergio smith

Comment: Would you please explain exactly what you mean by "we get humidity comming back through our return"? Do you see clouds of water vapor? Water dripping? Do you feel cold air coming out of the grille? Are you standing by the return with a hygrometer and seeing the humidity reading rise? Is the A/C indoor unit located above or below the return? Does the fan run for a few minutes after a cooling cycle?

Comment: Sergio, there's a lot of HVAC expertise available at this site, but your question is unclear and incomplete. I don't think you'll see any answers unless you reply to the request for details above. If you can't answer in a comment, you can click the EDIT link below your question and add the details to the question itself. Please answer all questions, they are all important to understanding and solving your problem.